# Find linear transformation with kernel given

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R^3}$  where $Ker(L)$ is spanned by $S=\{ \alpha_1=(1,2,3,4),\alpha_2=(0,1,1,1) \}$

What I am trying to do is let the linear transformation be defined as 
$$L((1,2,3,4))=(0,0,0)$$
$$L((0,1,1,1))=(0,0,0)$$
$$L((0,0,1,0))=(0,1,0)$$
$$L((0,0,0,1))=(0,0,1)$$

Let $(a,b,c,d)=c_1(1,2,3,4)+c_2(0,1,1,1)+c_3(0,0,1,0)+c_4(0,0,0,1)$

By solving the constants for all c,

I get $L((a,b,c,d))=(0,c-d-3a,d-b-4a)$ which is wrong when I substitute $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my steps?
Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to proceed if instead of the given kernel the range instead is given. For example : $T:V_3 \rightarrow V_3$ such that the equation of $R(T)$ is $4x_1-3x_2+x_3 = 0$. Should I post a new question for this ?

Comment: @roni You may post this as a new question but make sure that you do share what you have done so far. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply made an error in solving for $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$.  It should be
$$c_1=a\,,\quad c_2=b-2a\,,\quad c_3=c-b-a\,,\quad c_4=d-b-2a$$
which gives
$$L(a,b,c,d)=(0,\,c-b-a,\,d-b-2a)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

$L(0,1,0,0)=L(0,1,1,1)-L(0,0,1,0)-L(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0)-(0,1,0)-(0,0,1)=(0,-1,-1)$

$L(1,0,0,0)=L(1,2,3,4)-2L(0,1,0,0)-3L(0,0,1,0)-4L(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0)+(0,2,2)-(0,3,0)-(0,0,4)=(0,-1,-2)$

Now we know ho the function is defined on the canonical basis we can deduce:

$L(x,y,z,w)=(0,-x-y+z,-2x-y+w)$